# Tensor Flow - why I can't set a name for the assign operator

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to figure it out how TensorFlow serialised and deserialised a graph into a protobuf. Running this Python script I'm able to generate a checkpoint file that contain the protobuf (that I can use maybe to restore the graph later):

```
import tensorflow as tf


# variable
w = tf.get_variable(name="weights", dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer, use_resource=True)

# placeholders
x1 = tf.placeholder(name="x1", dtype=tf.float32)
x2 = tf.placeholder(name="x2", dtype=tf.float32)

# assign 
new_w = tf.assign(w, x1, name="assign")
new_w_again = tf.assign(w, x2, name="assign_again") # not used

# session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        before = sess.run(w)
        sess.run(new_w, feed_dict={x1: 10.0})
        after = sess.run(w)

        print("before/after: {}/{}".format(before, after))

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        path_to_checkpoint = saver.save(sess, "./../model-store-python/assign-model")
```

Just for completness the script works as expected and the output when I run it is:

```
before/after: [0.]/10.0
```

By the way, looking inside the protobuf I found that the two assign operations are referred by:

```
[protobuf stuff ...]

  node {
    name: "AssignVariableOp"
    op: "AssignVariableOp"
    input: "weights"
    input: "x1"
    attr {
      key: "dtype"
      value {
        type: DT_FLOAT
      }
    }
  }

  [... protobuf stuff ...]

  node {
    name: "AssignVariableOp_1"
    op: "AssignVariableOp"
    input: "weights"
    input: "x2"
    attr {
      key: "dtype"
      value {
        type: DT_FLOAT
      }
    }
  }

  [... protobuf stuff]
```

Why the two names of the assign operations are "AssignVariableOp" and "AssignVariableOp_1" instead of "assign" and "assign_again" ? I know it looks like a silly question but I need to have control over the node naming aspect in my project.

Comment: This is a bug, I'll send a pull request to fix it.

Comment: A temporary workaround is to do variable.assign(value, name=...) instead of tf.assign